# Extracting list data to CSV using CSOM - encoding issues

Tags: csom, .net, encoding

I have a very basic CSOM-based app that fetches data from SharePoint lists and writes them to CSV.

The **problem** is that when users open the resulting file in Excel, instead of certain characters like apostrophes, they get strings like `â€“`. Looks OK in Notepad.

I'm aware this is an issue with encoding - evidently Excel is expecting ASCII and is misinterpreting the input. I'd really like to understand how and where to fix this.

To write the CSV, I use a function like this, which I'm aware under the hood uses UTF-8 encoding:

```
Public Sub CSVWriter(ByVal CSVFile As String, ByVal theString As String)
    Using lf As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText(CSVFile)
        lf.WriteLine("{0}", theString)
        lf.Flush()
        lf.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

And call it like this:

```
CSVWriter("C:\My\File.csv",String.Format("{0},""{1}""", ID, Title))
```

Where `Title` is basically `ListItem("Title")`, after the list item has has been retrieved from SharePoint Online using `...GetItemByID(123)`.

Comment: I've just updated the CSVWriter such that the first line is now `Using lf As New IO.StreamWriter(CSVFile, True, Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"))` which seems to fix the issue, but I'm still keen to understand what's happening to ensure I'm not just hacking around something.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when I've run into this, it's because the data was copied from outside of SharePoint, like Word or Excel.

I usually have to run those characters either through a regex scrub or use something like Notepad++ and clean them out by hand.

Had to do something similar once with 10K+ rows, not fun.